# Where should I ask others to review my long codes about statistical algorithm?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My task is mainly to extract the core algorithm implemented in an R package written in R and Rcpp. I need to translate the codes to pure `R` and add few more features.

My codes seem to work reasonably, except for that the performance is obviously less satisfactory than the original package. I have checked my codes and algorithm several times and still found no clue about the problem.

I want to ask for someone to review my codes. However,

- The code is a bit longer than the average length posted on code reviews section of stack exchange.
- My goal is about a better performance.
- My problem requires knowledge about both code implementation and the statistical algorithm.

In my case, is there any place suitable for me to post my code review requirement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Odds of you getting an answer is slim, but [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is your best bet.

Code Review is pretty much the only site that accepts questions asking for blanket "review this code and give me feedback about performance optimization" questions. However, it still comes with limitations. Be sure to check [their help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). And be sure to reduce your code to the minimum required for a good review.

As always, the more domain knowledge reviewing your code requires, the less chance you have of getting an answer. They do have some answered Rcpp questions, but if it's a niche algorithm and knowledge about the algorithm is required that reduces the chance of finding someone to answer the question.

As a general note, Rcpp is often used to solve suboptimal performance, so you can't expect to rewrite Rcpp code in R and get similar performance. Which means there might not be anything to solve, it may just be that rewriting the code in R comes with a performance penalty that can only be avoided by writing the code in Rcpp